# Uncaught Rickshaw.Graph needs a reference to an element index.js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, rickshaw

When I use script tags in my index.html.erb the exact code runs fine but when I put the code in index.js.erb, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Rickshaw.Graph needs a reference to an element
```

I tried precompileing assets, really don't know what else to try...

also here is my application.js

```
//= require rickshaw_with_d3
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I did also try putting rickshaw on the bottom.  Don't yet understand in what order things are loaded in rails, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had js comments '//' in the js.erb file.  Those will stop it from loading because js.erb files are read as html and javascript by rails.